# What is the meaning of "animals had been named"?

Tags: idioms

Today I've read [this article](https://codahale.com/fan-in/) and I've found the following expression:

> *Later, when the **animals had been** named and everyone was running their blogs...*

So, what does ***animals had been named*** mean? Why in technical article the author writes about animals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the article you're reading, the quoted sentence is a part of a witty and informal way of marking time with a parallelism between the religious Genesis and the genesis of Internet activity. The author of the article *«need[s] to back up a bit.»*, so he begins:

- ***At the dawn of time***, when the earth was still new and everyone hosted their own websites [...];
- ***Later, when the animals had been named*** and everyone was running their blogs [...];
- ***Later still, when people began to walk on two legs*** and everyone gathered in central forums [...];
- ***Now, as the stars begin to dim*** and humans dip and swerve in flocks of social media ephemera [...];

In particular, animals being named is the subject of [Genesis 2:19](http://biblehub.com/genesis/2-19.htm):

> Now the LORD God had formed out of the ground all the wild animals and all the birds in the sky. **He brought them to the man to see what he would name them; and whatever the man called each living creature, that was its name**.

Answer (score 2):

It's a play off the metaphor he's working in, calling the birth of the internet "the dawn of time", and then referring to the book of Genesis in the Bible, when after God created everything, Adam went through the world and named all the animals.